# Using a variable in a case statement, within a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use a variable in a select statement (SQL Server 2008) and I am having some difficulty. I've included my code below.

```
DECLARE @newFieldName nvarchar(30)

SET @newFieldName = 'Variable 1'

SELECT 

SUM(CASE WHEN @newFieldName IN ('x', 'y' ,'z') then 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Default",

SUM(CASE WHEN @newFieldName NOT IN ('x', 'y' ,'z') then 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Not Default"

FROM table 1
```

I don't get the correct results. However when I use the below, I do.

```
SELECT 

SUM(CASE WHEN [Variable 1] IN ('x', 'y' ,'z') then 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Default",

SUM(CASE WHEN [Variable 1] NOT IN ('x', 'y' ,'z') then 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Not Default"

FROM [table 1]
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What is your question?  The expression:

```
'Variable 1' IN ('x', 'y' ,'z')
```

Is always going to return FALSE because you haven't included the string `'Variable 1'` in the list of accepted values.

The expression:

```
[Variable 1] IN ('x', 'y' ,'z')
```

will return TRUE when the variable contains one of those three values.

A constant string and the name of a column are two very different things.  If you want to have code where you can change the name of a column with a variable, you need to learn about dynamic SQL and `sp_executesql`.

EDIT:

The dynamic SQL version of what you are doing is:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
declare @newFieldName nvarchar(30);
set @newFieldName = 'Variable 1';

set @sql = '
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN @newFieldName IN ('x', 'y' ,'z') then 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Default",
       SUM(CASE WHEN @newFieldName NOT IN ('x', 'y' ,'z') then 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Not Default"
FROM table 1';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '@newFieldName', '['+@newFieldName+']');

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

However, you should start by reading the documentation on sp_executesql ([here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)) and learning about dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff. My question then is how can I use DECLARE/SET to declare [Variable 1]? This is probably a more complex task.

Answer (score 0):

your  @newFieldName is just a string: it does not "impersonate" the actual column in the table ...

I think that since your probably have only a handfull of columns which you are interested in, you could do something like

```
DECLARE @newFieldName nvarchar(30)

SET @newFieldName = 'Variable 1'

SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN @newFieldName = 'Variable 1' and [Variable 1] IN ('x', 'y' ,'z') then 1
         WHEN @newFieldName = 'Variable 2' and [Variable 2] IN ('x', 'y' ,'z') then 1 ELSE 0
    END) as [Default],
SUM(CASE WHEN @newFieldName = 'Variable 1' and [Variable 1] NOT IN ('x', 'y' ,'z') then 1
     WHEN @newFieldName = 'Variable 2' and [Variable 2] NOT IN ('x', 'y' ,'z') then 1 ELSE 0
END) as [Not Default],

FROM table 1
```

This way you avoid dynamic sql, but of course will get ugly quickly with more column possibilities

Comment: I have a number of columns. This SELECT statement is actually sitting within a loop. I am reading newFieldName from a table of column names. Thanks though.